# how to set numpy input of None

Tags: python, numpy, keras

```
self.model = Sequential()
self.model.add(Dense(units=20, input_dim=9))
self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
self.model.add(Dense(units=len(labels)))
self.model.add(Activation('softmax'))
self.model.compile(optimizer='sgd', #  rmsprop
                   loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                   metrics=['accuracy'])

x = np.array([[0] * 9])
print('x {} {}'.format(x.shape, x))
a = self.model.predict(x)
```

that gives

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

It does not make sense at all.

```
    x = np.array([0] * 9)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 9) but got array with shape (9, 1)

Please help the welp

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit confusing in my opinion but the solution is simple. If your input array has the shape `(x, y, z)`, the expected input shape for predict is `(n, x, y, z`) where `n` is the number of samples (1 in your case).

Just use

`self.model.predict(x.reshape((1, ) + x.shape))`

Comment: that gives `x (1, 9) [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]` and `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: Strange... I tried your code (replacing `self.model` with `model` and adding `from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *`) and it works without problems.